# Flutter and Dart and Future. Is this a known feature of Dart Futures and null?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

In the code below (Dart 2.4.0 Windows), returning null from a future that indicates a return type of String results in:

```
I/flutter ( 8735): The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
I/flutter ( 8735): type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String>'
```

If I return "null as String;", VSCode shows a warning "unnecessary cast", however, the code works and I don't get the fatal error.
The Code in question is below. I have commented out the line that was causing the problem and now return "null as String".
I use a null String all the time in Dart without a problem, so it only appears to be a problem with Futures AFAIK.
Is this just a known fact about Dart and Futures and this is the workaround ("return null as String")?

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); 
    Future<String> future = _initPreferences();
    future.then((sError) {
      if (sError != null) debugPrint("\n*** Error from initPrefs = $sError\n");
      if (sError == null) debugPrint("\n***Preferences were initialized OK\n");
    });
  }

  Future<String> _initPreferences() {
    return SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      _prefs = prefs;
      //return null;
      return null as String;
    }).catchError((vError) {
      return "Unable to load categories";
    });
  }
```

Comment: null is clearly not a String and can't be casted. You could return "dynamic" (Future<dynamic>) and check later once the Future is done.

Comment: Returning "null as String" works fine.

Comment: You'd need to change your async logic. "await" your SharedPreference response, if you have the correct value, return that value, if the value is incorrect, then return null (and null directly). That's it, then you can match your Future<String> which should be an async method now and check if sError is null or not. (replace sError with a more friendly parameter as "value" or something like that).

Comment: Possibly Dart 2.4.0 has some bugs. Yeah... Thanks to the developers

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a type when using `Future.then`, so it has to be inferred.  Since you return `null`, it doesn't know what type it's supposed to be, so your call to `Future.then` does not return a `Future<String>`.

You can help the inference engine along by explicitly specifying the type via `then<String>(...)`:

```dart
Future<String> _initPreferences() {
  return SharedPreferences.getInstance().then<String>((prefs) {
    _prefs = prefs;
    return null;
  }).catchError((vError) {
    return "Unable to load categories";
  });
}
```

although even better would be to just use `async` and `await`:

```dart
Future<String> _initPreferences() async {
  try {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _prefs = prefs;
    return null;
  } catch (vError) {
    return "Unable to load categories";
  }
}
```

---

Here is a simpler reproduction case:

```dart
Future<String> foo() {
  final future = Future(() => null);
  print('${future.runtimeType}');
  return future;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  await foo();
}
```

I would expect `future` to be a `Future<Null>`, but it ends up being a `Future<dynamic>` instead, and I'm not sure why. (`Null` is special and allows `Future<Null>` to be assigned to `Future<T>`.) I suspect it might be a bug since `dartanalyzer` does not generate any warnings about it. (And contrary to what some comments say, this does not seem to be new to Dart 2.4.0; I tried with Dart 2.3.0, 2.3.2, and 2.4.0.) I've filed [an issue about it](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37402).

Answer (score 0):

Someone did post what appears to be the correct answer, but then it somehow disappeared, so I can't take credit. The whole point of the exercise is that I want to use a Future (not await) The answer was/is: (then)

```
 Future<String> _initPreferences() {
    return SharedPreferences.getInstance().then<String>((prefs)
```

Comment: After I posted my answer, I realized that my explanation was not entirely correct.  I'll revise it and repost.

Comment: This is not an answer. This is workaround. Using an outdated programming style is not the right solution. It is more like an act in case of hopelessness.

Comment: @mezoni. It's what I'm researching and it's valid Dart.

Comment: Thank you for your `researching`! You have done a very necessary `researching`.

Comment: @mezoni When I see things on SO that don't interest me, I just move on. I recommend it because it saves time.

Comment: I think the problem is that in the previous version 2.3.2 everything worked fine. Therefore, your answer is an attempt to get out of the situation when something stops working after the update and you are trying to find a solution that would save you from this problem. Yes, I agree with you that your solution works. But in fact, in this way, you only avoided this problem, but it cannot be recommended as a correct solution.

Comment: @mezoni What evidence is there that this is a problem with Dart 2.4.0 but not 2.3.2?

Comment: Therefore, I also have similar problems after upgrading to version 2.4.0. Make a conclusion yourself.

Comment: @mezoni I can reproduce the problem with Dart 2.3.0, 2.3.2, and 2.4.0.

Comment: When I wrote `similar` problem I don't mean `the same`. I mean similar problem with the analyzer when it displays the warnings but all works fine (as you wrote). So I ignore these warnings. This happens only in the last SDK version.

Comment: @mezoni How is that even *similar* then?  The OP received *runtime failures*, not analyzer warnings.  Also, the whole point of *warnings* (rather than *errors*) is to report *potential* problems that might actually work at runtime.  It seems to me that you are complaining about something completely unrelated.

Comment: Oh well. You're right. Write a thank you note to the developers.